# Inserir valor no array mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Minha model funciona da seguinte forma. Um usuário possui documentos, mas o usuário se cadastra antes de ter esses documentos. O que basicamente estou tentando fazer é dar um Update em usuários no array de documentos.
**SCHEMA**

```
'user strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    documents: [
        {
        title: {
            type: String
        },
        content: {
            type: String
        },
        notes: [
            {
            note: {
            type: String
            }
        }
    ]
    }
]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Então busquei algumas possíveis respostas e cheguei a isto
**QUERY**

```
exports.put = (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    User
    .update({id}, {
        $push: {
            "documents.$.title": req.body.title,
            "documents.$.content": req.body.content
        }
    }).then(x => {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: 'Usuário atualizado com sucesso!'
        });
    }).catch(e => {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Falha ao atualizar o Usuário =(', data: e
        });
    });  
};
```

Ele não retorna erro, cai no THEN e dá como se o usuário tivesse sido atualizado com sucesso. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira correta de usar o push é assim:

```
exports.put = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    const document = {
        title: 'Teste',
        content: 'Teste',
        notes: [
            {note: 'note1'},
            {note: 'note2'}
        ],
        // Por qual motivo notes é um array de objetos e não somente um array?
        // notes: ['note1', 'note2']
    }

    await User.updateOne({ id }, { $push: { documents: document } })
    .then(x => {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: 'Usuário atualizado com sucesso!'
        });
    })
    .catch(e => {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Falha ao atualizar o Usuário =(', data: e
        });
    });  
};
```

O que o push faz é inserir no array documents um novo objeto de document. O jeito mais fácil e inclusive melhor de ler é colocar o objeto fora do updateOne.

Te aconselho também usar algum linter. Eu utilizo o JSLINT para manter um código limpo e uniforme. Mesmo trabalhando sozinho, é interessante no caso de outros programadores ajudar no futuro. E até para manter boas práticas de programação. Utilizo o JSLINT do airbnb.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela atenção e pelas dicas. Graças a sua resposta consegui resolver e estou organizando melhor o código. Sobre o notes realmente era um array, não era para se um array de objetos, obrigada por ter notado.

Comment: Que bom, fico feliz que tenha ajudado. =]